# Shall we have a drop down list to select communities while saving profile details?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

Currently, in the edit profile section, we have two buttons:

**Save changes just for this community** and **Save and copy changes to all stack exchange communities**.

[image]

Instead a drop down check box list will be helpful to select the communities in which I want my changes to appear.

#### Scenario

I want the same details for sites Stack Overflow, Software Engineering, CS Educators, Code Review, and Computer Science.

Another set of information for Software recs and Hardware recs.

Another set of information for Travel and Expats.

#### Currently

I have to edit on one community. Then copy the details and update each communities manually. For the first case, edit five communities manually.

#### Proposal

Add a dropdown checkbox list to select the target communities in which the information should be updated.

[image]

#### Advantage

- Whenever I update some details in my profile, I am able to update the same for selected set of communities. No need to copy and paste it on each communities one by one.

> We're able to set different details for different communities. So Stack Overflow stores the profile information of each community differently and hence no need to alter the database for this.